# JavaCV java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError Error on Windows 7 64bit

Tags: 64-bit, javacv

> I have JDK 7(64bit) Netbeans 7.2 and OpenCV 2.4. I already set the
>   path variable by adding the relavant OpenCV paths. But the program
>   stile give the that error when executing.

I already run my program on 32bit environment with JDK7(32bit) Netbeans 7.2 and OpenCV 2.4; In that case the programe execute perfectly.

Can any one help me to figure out the problem when i use 64bit environment

Answer (score 2):

1. Install JDK7 (64 bit).
2. Copy the OpenCV directory to your windows (C) drive.
3. Install microsoft c++ 2010 redistributable x64.
4. Make "C:\opencv\build\common\tbb" as yor path in environment variables.
5. Download javacv-0.1.jar and make this as your library file in your project.
6. If the problem exist download cv100.dll, cvcam100.dll,cxcore100.dll,opencv_highgui220.dll    from internet and copy this to system32.